# php regex get Keywords between special characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex in PHP to keywords in the URLs

```
$url="https://example.com/search/node/KEYWORD1/loc=11";
$url="https://example.com/search/node/KEYWORD2";
$url="https://example.com/search/node/KEYWORD3/loc=9";
preg_match('search/node/\K\d+/', $url,$m);
$KEYWORD=  $m[0];
```

$KEYWORD returns all the url. How can return only the KEYWORDS in URLs?

thanks for your helps

Comment: You have to use delimiters for the pattern. Try `preg_match('~search/node/\K\d+~', $url,$m);`

Comment: @Thefourthbird not work dud !

Comment: I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your pattern to match any char except a whitespace character or a `/` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Your pattern currently matches 1+ digits only.

Note that if you want to use the `/` as a delimiter, you have to add it to the start as wel and escape the forward slashes inside the pattern.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MTRTI7/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IBbke)

```
$url="https://example.com/search/node/Star/loc=9";
preg_match('/search\/node\/\K[^\s\/]+/', $url,$m);
$KEYWORD=  $m[0];
echo $KEYWORD;
```

Output

```
Star
```

If you would use a different delimiter you code might look like

```
preg_match('~search/node/\K[^\s/]+~', $url,$m);
```

Comment: @BijanZand Then you could add the `?` to the character class to exclude it from matching https://regex101.com/r/5tgbgd/1 You might take a look at [parseurl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) as well.

Comment: mr @Thefourthbird if keyword have space ! how regex that ? Like `https://example.com/search/node/KEYWORD Keyword?page=5`

Comment: Then you can remove the `\s` from the character class. If you dont want to match newlines you can replace the `\s` with `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can put parenthesis around what you want to capture : the first group will be available in `$m[1]` :

```
$url="https://example.com/search/node/KEYWORD3/loc=9";
preg_match('|search/node/([^/]+)/?|', $url,$m);
$KEYWORD=  $m[1]; // KEYWORD3
```

Comment: (KEYWORD) are variable my friend !

Comment: like: `https://example.com/search/node/Star/loc=9` OR  `https://example.com/search/node/Sky/loc=12` OR  `https://example.com/search/node/whine`

Comment: I edited the regex to look at variable keyword (+ make / optional at the end)